# usb mouse not working after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: usb, upgrade, 16.04, mouse

I recently upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS. Problem is my USB logitech RX250 optical mouse doesn't work anymore. USB Keyboard works just fine. The mouse is recognized so it seems. Tried the suggested solution with rmod and modprobe but that didn't work.

lsusb outout below:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
```

Dmesg also shows (un)plugging the mouse:

```
[ 1947.868807] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1950.009016] usb 1-5: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1950.180005] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c050
[ 1950.180011] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1950.180014] usb 1-5: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[ 1950.180016] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1950.180186] usb 1-5: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[ 1950.186203] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:046D:C050.0007/input/input21
[ 1950.237268] hid-generic 0003:046D:C050.0007: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
```

Comment: Haven't been able to solve it (xinput didn't show the mouse).  Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from scratch. USB mouse works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to Gnome Software. To stop this from happening we can disable the Gnome Software from startup applications.

Here are the steps to solve this issue:-

1:-Open the dash and search for "startup applications" and open it.

2:-Disable Gnome Software (Uncheck the box on the left side).

3:-Close it.

4:-Shutdown or restart and check it again.

this time your mouse will start working.

the same question was asked by some other guy and i just found the solution yesterday.I hope Developers will solve the issue soon in Gnome Software.

**UPDATE**:

i solved the problem with

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: @HenryM try (sudo rmmod usbhid) I hope it should work as these both things, the one i posted in answer and this command works for me.

Comment: just gives me `ERROR: Module usbhid is not currently loaded`